# Code igniter - Special Characters/Date in URL

Tags: php

Codeigniter has this configuration setting

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';
```

using which we can specify which characters are allowed in the query string.

I have to accept date in my URL, the format is : Y/m/d H:i:s

The normal code igniter allowed URL character set is not allowing this date. For now I have set `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` as empty but that's obviously a security threat.  Please let me know which regex expression will work for this.

Comment: Colons `:` in a URL are not a good idea: They are reserved characters with a specific function (Specifying the port number in a host name). You should choose a different separator, e.g. `.` or `-`

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is a simple routing

go to

```
application/config
```

and open the routes.php and add the following configuration

```
$route['notes/(:num)/(:any)'] = "notes/view/$3";
```

for more information visit for [URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)